# javac not working in CMD

Tags: java, cmd

I'm having a issue with compiling java from my Command Prompt. At first it was saying javac isn't a recognised internal or external command and by reading up I see you need to change the path and thats what I did exactly to...

variable name: path

variable value:%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%path%;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;

I closed commpand prompt and attempted it again however the same issue came up.

I then tried echo %path% and the entire path line was echoed(entire line in terms of that variable value)

I also have tried "for %i in (javac.exe) do @echo %~$PATH:i" and that returns ECHO ON.

I'm quite stumped and confused now. My javafile is in and named main.java however I am trying to compile it whilst in the javawork folder in CMD

C:\Users\MYNAME\Documents\Javawork

Thanks,

Comment: Look up the javac.exe it is sureley *NOT* in jre/bin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the path to the **JDK**, not the JRE, in your system path. The JRE doesn't come with a compiler (javac).

Comment: +1 - looking back, the differentiation between JRE and JDK was perhaps one of the dumbest decisions ever made! Think of 100s of saved SO questions :) Yet, it is not too late to correct it .... it's not the 90ies anymore were disk space is scarce and measured in single digit gigabytes ....

Comment: Nah, not stupid; just a beginner's thing. It's a subtle distinction - no worries.

Answer (score 2):

To compile Java code you need to install the [Java Development Kit](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) (JDK) as javac.exe isn't included in the Java Runtime Environment (JRE).

The path should point to the `bin`directory of the JDK.